# Google Colab: CalledProcessError with %%python after %%shell

Tags: python, shell, google-colaboratory

I started a Google Colab cell with %shell to run some shell code, then tried to run python code by switching back with %%python, but no matter what code I tried, I always get CalledProcessError for the last shell command before %%python, how to solve this? I need them to be in the same cell.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%%python` line is being executed as a shell command and leads to the initial error. What's needed is a way of logging out of the shell and returning control to the cell. Using `exit` causes the cell to exit completely. Perhaps you could call `python` directly as shown below.

```
%%shell
echo "hello from shell"
python -c 'print("hello from Python")'
```

This gives the following.

```
hello from shell
hello from Python
```

Comment: A second question...